# Would the motor reverse if phases swapped for this case?

Tags: motor, servo, electrical

A [servomotor](https://www.kollmorgen.com/en-us/products/catalogs/kollmorgen-akm-servomotor-selection-guide/) power connection pins are given as follows:

[image]

U V W are the three phase terminals. Would the motor reverse if I mistakenly swap phases U and V namely if I connect pin 1 to W and pin 3 to U? Is this a synchronous motor or induction?

Motor nameplate:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a 3-phase permanent magnet (PM) servomotor. Induction motors do not have permanent magnets, therefore it is a synchronous motor.

If any two phase connections between the motor and controller are swapped, the motor will reverse. Since the controller can reverse the motor electronically, it may make no difference how the motor is wired during installation. However, if the motor phase sequence does not match the resolver sequence, the controller may not operate properly.

If the controller has three-phase input, swapping those phases will not reverse the motor.